# Select list of objects using a LINQ query

Tags: c#, sql, class, entity-framework-6, linq-query-syntax

I have an object list like this. Object is type of TBLM_PRODUCT this is the entity framework generated class for my database table TBLM_PRODUCT. My TBLM_PRODUCT  class looks like this

```
public partial class TBLM_PRODUCT
    {
        public string PRODUCT_CODE { get; set; }
        public string PRODUCT_DESC { get; set; }
        public string PRODUCT_ISBN { get; set; }
        public string PRODUCT_SUPPLIER { get; set; }
        public string PRODUCT_PROGROUP { get; set; }
        public string PRODUCT_MEDIUM { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> PRODUCT_ACTIVE { get; set; }

    }
```

I have declared my list like this.
    private IEnumerable myList= new List();

I'm getting objects to list like this

```
myList = RAEntity.TBLM_PRODUCT.ToList<DataControllers.TBLM_PRODUCT>();
```

I want to query this list to get items which are active. 
In a normal sql query I can do it like this.

```
select * from TBLM_PRODUCT where PRODUCT_ACTIVE = 1;
```

I need to select a list of objects. 
How can  achieve it using a LINQ query?

Answer (score 1):

This...

```
RAEntity.TBLM_PRODUCT
    .Where(x => x.PRODUCT_ACTIVE == 1)
    .ToList<DataControllers.TBLM_PRODUCT>();
```

will be translated by EF to...

```
select * from TABLE where Active = 1
```

Just make sure the `Where` extensions is called before to `List`. However, I'm just a bit puzzled as to why the `PRODUCT_ACTIVE` data type is `decimal`?